# Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Prove that $\lvert X^Y \lvert =\lvert X\lvert^{\lvert Y \lvert}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$Y^X$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. The set of all functions with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$ is written $Y^X$ .

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Prove that
$\lvert X^Y \lvert =\lvert X\lvert^{\lvert Y \lvert}$.

**Note**( the set of all functions from some set $X$ into p2q is in bijective correspondence with $$\mathcal{P}(X)$$)

I have no idea how to start this proof, please give me some help.

Comment: Induction on $|Y|$?

Comment: First work through the example of $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y = \{a, b, c\}$. Work through it in detail. Write down all the functions. You'll see what's going on. In fact, work out all the elements of $X^Y$ and $Y^X$.

Comment: Please Edit the 2nd part of the Question. It cant be understood.

Answer (score 1):

For any sets $X$ and $Y$, the set of all functions $f : X \to Y$ is denoted $ Y^X.$

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets — say, $|X| = n$ and $|Y | = m$. Without loss of
generality, you could let $X = \{1, \ldots , n\}$ and $Y = \{1, \ldots , m\}$.

Consider  $ 1_X $ ( 1 belonging to $X$ ), it has $m$ options or choices in $Y$ to map in $Y$ as a function.

Similarly, for every element in $X$ has $m$ options in $Y$ to map into.

So for the whole set $X$, there are exactly $m \times m \times m \times m\times\cdots\times m$ ($n$ times) choices to map as a function into $Y$.

Therefore, $|Y^X |= m^n $

Hence the total number of function from  $f : X \to Y$ is $ m^n = |Y|^{|X|} $.

QED